# Python 3.5 regular expression matching for directories

Tags: python, regex

I am using the Python 3.5 `re` module with this code:

```
>>> test
'\\\\192.168.1.2\\shared\\Department\\Travel\\FY 2015\\Travel Expense Statement Jul 25 2019.pdf'
```

I want to return `Department\Travel\FY 2015\Travel Expense Statement Jul 25 2019.pdf`. I have tried the following regex, but keep getting errors such as `sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 12`

```
x=re.compile( "shared\\[^\\](*?)" )
print( x.findall(test) )
```

or the empty result `['']` for:

```
x=re.compile( "shared\\\(.*?)" )
```

How can I accomplish this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your *regular expression* is very simple, remove the `?` character in your second regular expression. You just need `.*` that matches zero or more characters.

`*?` together means a lazy quantifier that matches as little as possible, so if you use `.*?`, it means "zero or more any characters, but as few as possible". As for the first regular expression, the `*` does not have a preceding atom to which it could apply to, hence the error.

---

In general case, you should rather use the `ntpath` module as in [kennytm's answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39088502/918959).

Comment: @Antti: Thanks. I have been fiddling around with this and thought I had tried that variation, but I guess not.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use regex for this. Instead, use the [`ntpath` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive) (or `os.path` if you are sure the script will only run on Windows):

```
>>> s = '\\\\192.168.1.2\\shared\\Department\\Travel\\FY 2015\\Travel Expense Statement Jul 25 2019.pdf'
>>> import ntpath
>>> ntpath.splitdrive(s)
('\\\\192.168.1.2\\shared', '\\Department\\Travel\\FY 2015\\Travel Expense Statement Jul 25 2019.pdf')
>>> ntpath.splitdrive(s)[1][1:]
'Department\\Travel\\FY 2015\\Travel Expense Statement Jul 25 2019.pdf'
```

Comment: Great job cutting to the root of the XY problem.

Comment: @kennytm: Thanks. I narrowed down the question as small as possible.  The REs are stored in a .ini file and are therefore not strictly nt paths.  However, I did not know about the ntpath module and will definitely be using it in the future!